# how to run 64-bit apps on 32-bit architecture

Tags: windows

I  have an 64-bit software and i need to install it on a 32-bit architecture computer.
I want to know whether Is there a way to execute 64-bit windows applications on 32-bt architecture.

thanks

Comment: you can't as much as I know, the backward compatibility is not possible , however you can run them in 32 bit mode by right clicking on your app  - properties - compatibility - Run this program in compatibility mode

Comment: Only by using an emulator, e.g., Bochs, and installing 64-bit Windows in the virtual environment.  Performance is unlikely to be adequate.

Comment: @BrijRajSingh: nonsense - compatibility mode does not allow a 64-bit program to run on a 32-bit computer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston i didn't even said that you can run a 64 bit on 32 bit, i said " however you can run them in 32 bit mode by right clicking on your app - properties - compatibility - Run this program in compatibility mode – "  'them' doesn't mean a 64 bit on 32 bit machine.

Comment: @BrijRajSingh: if the application is 32-bit, then there's no reason to think compatibility mode would be needed.  If it is 64-bit, then it won't help.  Either way it's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7

In a nutshell: No you can't do that.

I have read up on using a Virtual Machine run a 64-bit guest OS when you have a 32-bit host machine, but that's only if you had a 64-bit processor to begin with.

Comment: A virtual machine solution that uses an emulator (such as Bochs) would work, at least in principle.  But in practice I don't think the OS would run well enough to be useful.